# Ionic.Zip Splitt up zip can't be extracted

Tags: c#, zip, 7zip

I zip a directory with Ionic.Zip and splitt it up into several files. The result is a bunch of files named myfile.zip, myfile.z01, myfile.z02,...

When I look into the zip-File with windows explorer, I can see the file list.

But when I try to extract the archive with windows explorer, I get a message **The same volume can not be used as both the source and destination**

When I open the zipfile with 7zip I get the message **file myfile.zip cannot be opened as archive**

Creating and extracting a single zip-archive works fine.

Here is the code, where I create the zip archive, using Ionic.Zip

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    //zip.AlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    zip.AddDirectory(sourceDirectory);
    //zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 0; //Single file
    zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 1024 * 1024 * 8; //Splitt up into 8 MB pieces
    //zip.Password = zipPassword;
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.None;
    zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.None;

    zip.Save(zipFilePath);    

    segmentsCreated = zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave;
}

return segmentsCreated;
```

Btw, I tried several combinations of CompressionLevels, CompressionMethods, with and without password,... No changes :(

**UPDATE 1:**

Unpacking works:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFilePath))
{
     zip.Password = zipPassword;
     zip.ExtractAll(targetDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.
you can't open a partial zip file using the windows explorer.
Use [WinRar](https://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).